# Are Xamarin iOS apps bloated unreasonably?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm developing a reasonably simple app using Xamarin iOS and the smallest size I've gotten for the .app file is 13.5 MB.

I've performed all the recommended optimizations - no debug symbols, LVVM code generation, thumb-2, link all assemblies, single architecture only (ARMV7).

The first question is, does my 13.5 MB sound like something to be expected from Xamarin iOS, or am I likely doing something wrong?

The second question is, how much extra size overhead does Xamarin iOS add to an equivalent native implementation (roughly)?

The third question is, roughly how small can a Hello World app get compiled down to using Xamarin iOS?

The fourth question is, roughly how small can a native Hello World app get compiled down to?

Comment: use "SDK Assemblies Only"

Comment: @eMi: despite the claims made by the documentation, linking SDK Assemblies only actually made the app larger - 14.3 mb.

Comment: uhm ok well I dont know how's your exactly setup.. made 4 Apps and there is also a pretty "big" app and its size is 6.8 Mb.. ur definitly doing something wrong mhm... maybe I provide tomorrow an answer as I dont have access now to any sourcecode

Comment: @eMi: that's good to know.. that sort of size is very reasonable and won't upset my client. I've imported a lot of reusable common code from other projects which isn't being used. The documentation seems to imply the linker would ignore this, but do you think it could be affecting it?

Comment: *despite the claims made by the documentation* -> **Link SDK** is a subset of **Link all**, so **Link all** < **Link SDK** (default) < **Don't link**. If some documentation is wrong (or confusing) please include a link to it so we can fix it.

Comment: @poupou: link is at http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/memory_perf_best_practices  where it says -- The following steps will help keep this size down:
Set the linker option to Link SDK assemblies.

Comment: @eMi: Are you sure that was not "16.8" MB? The "Advanced iOS Build Mechanics" slides seem to suggest the best they got their sample to was still over 10MB. They also show how some people managed to shave a quater or even a half a meg here and there.. What should I tell my client that his simple 4 screen app with no multimedia is over 12 MB? It's embarassing.

Comment: @HermanSchoenfeld now that you say it, you're making me doubtful. I will take a look at tomorrow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.dSYM` is a directory that includes debugging symbols. This is **not** something you're shipping as part of your application (to your end users). Note that this is produced even in non-debugging builds since it allows you to symbolicate crash reports (that comes from end users running the *release* binary).

For the *real* application size you need to look at the `.app` directory.

You can learn quite a few tricks to reduce your application size (and build time) by watching this year [Evolve](http://xamarin.com/evolve/2013) video **[Advanced iOS Build mechanics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIDI2d86zTE)**. That will also answer the other questions you had.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It's actually worse - 16.7 MB.

Comment: I've reduced it to 13.5 MB using link-all. Is this what you expect with Xamarin iOS?

Comment: Slide 21 implies that 10.9MB is "the best size" for the "Field Service Sample" application. So I take it the lack of response implies a size of 10 - 15 MB is the expected minimum for release builds?

Comment: No. An HelloWorld app is under 3MB. Application size vary with your code and the *non-code assets* (e.g. images, videos, sounds, database...) that you include inside it. In some application the *assets* can be very large. E.g. all the launch images, for all devices/orientations (in particular when iPad retina versions are included), can be much larger than the application executable itself. OTOH assets size are identical whatever tool you're using to build iOS applications.

Comment: There are no assets in my app and it's 12MB. It seems that as soon as the code starts to use the libraries the size grows geometrically likely due to AOT'ing all possible generics and code dependency tree's. Am I wrong? Is there an example of an app of the complexity of a twitter app that is within 3mb range? (no assets needed)

Comment: @HermanSchoenfeld An HelloWorld is under 3MB - you won't find an example of a Twitter app in that range. An example would be **TweetStation**, written in C# (which includes assets: images and sounds), without **Link all** (default Link SDK) and re-compressed by Apple store (which results in larger size than the original) is 8.8MB https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/tweetstation/id375611783?mt=8

Comment: Using generics is more costly because there will be more generated code (i.e. it's much more concise in C# than in native code). OTOH we have generic sharing code (including support for value-types in 6.4+) that limit the growth. Even a minimal HelloWorld app will include a lot of them since it includes parts of the BCL which internally uses generics. So it will grow - but doubling your application code will not *normally* double the size of the native app (note that using generics/LINQ requires less C# source code than ObjC would need and, even if you dont write, it is still needed natively).

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin apps are a bit larger in release mode, as one would expect. As an example, looking at my binaries from two shipping apps, the binary + dlls are around 12m and 18m (I think I need to look into why the 18m one is so much bigger...). I would guess if I had done these in objective-c they would have been around half that size, from past experience building native apps.

If you're running debug hardware builds, they are *enormous*. the 12m example above jumps up to 96M (?!) for binary + dlls. Before I checked this, I had in my head that they doubled in size to deal with software debugger, but I guess there's a whole lot of other crap going in that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Except the initial *hit* (including the runtime library) the size growth should be linear and similar to ObjC. You might want to look at your managed linker settings (e.g. the default **Link SDK** vs the more optimized **Link All**) and how you natively link (if you have bindings to native libraries). Both subjects are part of the video mentioned above.

Comment: Assuming linking is working properly, it will grow faster (beyond the initial hit) than objective-c as you link in more and more of the mono frameworks. Objective-c is linking into system frameworks that are not included in the binary.

Comment: Why does it include the DLL's if the code is fully linked natively? Are they still used somehow? Thanks for your helpful answer btw.

Comment: @poupou: why should it grow linearly since as the app increases its use of the API's, much more of the code is AOT'd due to dependency graphs and potential generics. e.g. calling Sum() on a List<int> would result in AOT'ing IEnumerable<int>, ICollection<int, IList<int>, List<int> and other internal dependencies just for int.  Is this wrong?

Comment: Assemblies (`.dll` and `.exe`) are needed since they include the .NET metadata. By default there is **no** IL inside them in the **release** configuration (it's stripped away). That bit of information is also part of my video ;-)

Comment: @poupou: thanks for the links, I read your slides and watched the video. Even though I learned a lot, I havent been able to reduce the size of my app. Given what's going on and the benefits, I suppose it's not unreasonable to have 15mb app.

Comment: @HermanSchoenfeld It's hard to say a size is *right* or not without seeing the application source code and all build options. I've seen a lot of smaller and (some much) bigger applications. Often their sizes were not optimal - which is why I did that talk at Evolve. However if you're following all my guidelines then you should be close to the smallest binary possible with tools.