# How can I minimize the size of ipa file of my Xamarin.form iOS application?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have created a cross platform Xamarin Application. When I debugged it by Ad-Hoc and Appstore it gave me ipa file of size 13.9MB which is too large.

How can I reduce it? I am using many dll such as Xlab, sqlite, xamarin.forms, etc.
I even tried to zip and unzip the ipa file and the resulting Monotouch 32 and Monotouch 64 size is much bigger. How can I reduce the size. I even tried the Linker to link all the assemblies but still the size is 13.9MB.

Comment: Too large for what? IPA files can range from small to huge depending on the app, and the OTA limit is around 50MB.

Comment: As per the requirement need ipa file below 10MB.

Comment: Have you looked at this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/19010957/1107580

Comment: Thank u Iain Smith