# How to reduce the size of Xamarin.Forms applications?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I am developing Xamarin.Forms application for iPad. When i build application in release mode, Application will be 46MB size.

Please have a look below iOS build configuration:
[image]

Comment: It is hard to tell without looking at your actual code but here is a  list of possible things to review. https://gist.github.com/jgold6/a1e60e0bb24ccdd2b2b8

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40610209/ipa-file-size-issue-in-xamarin-ios) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19010957/7196681) might answer your question.

Comment: @Curiousity, I already followed evolve steps and also decreased app size 66MB to 46MB. 46MB is still more. If i create this app in ObjectiveC it will be 20MB.